# How to merge two pd.DataFrames base on different timestamps and value restriction

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

1# I want to merge two `pandas DataFrames` of different length based on their timestamps. The timestamps do not align 100%.

2# The DataFrames have a column with e.g., an animal type and some values. The DataFrames should also be merged based on the animal type.

For issue number 1# I can use `numpy.searchsorted()`, However, this will not regard the animal type.

In the result image below, you can see, that Cat and Dogs are mixed due to the "correct" timestamp. **How could I add the restriction that animal type has to be equal for the sorting via `np.searchsorted()`?**

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand

start = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 23)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [start + dt.timedelta(minutes=rand.randrange(60)) for i in range(9)],'B':['Dog','Cat','Dog','Dog','Dog','Cat','Cat','Dog','Dog'], 'C': [1] * 9}).sort_values('A').reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': [start + dt.timedelta(minutes=rand.randrange(60)) for i in range(10)],'E':['Cat','Dog','Cat','Dog','Cat','Cat','Dog','Cat','Dog','Cat'], 'F': [2] * 10}).sort_values('D').reset_index(drop=True)

df2.index = np.searchsorted(df1.A.values, df2.D.values)
print(pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left'))
```

[image]

thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks to BENY, I checked `merge_asof()`. however, it does not seem to take different sized DataFrames into consideration.

My Problem is that my real data consists of one very large (2M) and one smaller (10k) DataFrame. The merge result should find the few spots where the smaller Data Frame can add information to the larger dataFrame.

With `merge_asof()` the large DataFrame would be reduced to the smaller size. numpy.searchsorted() does that, however, I did not manage to add the second restriction. I have not seen an any option for `merge_asof()`.

One idea would be to first split the data on the animal type, do my fitting, and then merge them again. However, my original data would result in over 500 single DataFrames. I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can check `merge_asof`

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='A', right_on='D', 
                    left_by='B', right_by='E', 
                    direction = 'nearest'  )
Out[109]: 
                    A    B  C                   D    E  F
0 2021-12-23 00:09:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:10:00  Dog  2
1 2021-12-23 00:14:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:17:00  Dog  2
2 2021-12-23 00:27:00  Cat  1 2021-12-23 00:33:00  Cat  2
3 2021-12-23 00:35:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:24:00  Dog  2
4 2021-12-23 00:37:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:24:00  Dog  2
5 2021-12-23 00:42:00  Cat  1 2021-12-23 00:40:00  Cat  2
6 2021-12-23 00:43:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:24:00  Dog  2
7 2021-12-23 00:46:00  Dog  1 2021-12-23 00:24:00  Dog  2
8 2021-12-23 00:52:00  Cat  1 2021-12-23 00:47:00  Cat  2
```

Comment: Question? Does it also consider the different size? Meaning, that it does not just fill from the beginning, but also add NaN or NaT if none is fitting for the particular index? Thanks